# Target hamburger nav collapse in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I would like to style the hamburger menu in the nav when content is collapsed, what class do I target to do this?

The class name has changed for this since Alpha 5.

The class "collapsed" is only added to the button after it's been clicked twice.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `collapsed` class to the markup since that's the initial state of the toggler..

`<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">`

http://www.codeply.com/go/HtUNXrHoQl

Comment: Ah of course, I've now switched the styles around and that works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is why RC's should **not** be used in production. Things change. A lot.

To find the classes, just take a look at the HTML in the alpha 6 [example template](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/):

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

The class on the `button` is `navbar-toggler` and the class on the span is `navbar-toggler-icon`.